# OpenGL Compute Shader Binding Point Redundancy

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I wrote my first OGL compute shader.  After many hours and examples I finally got things working.  One of the sections of programs I don't understand is block indices and binding points. (Following this [example](http://www.geeks3d.com/20140704/tutorial-introduction-to-opengl-4-3-shader-storage-buffers-objects-ssbo-demo/) among others.)

My computer shader has:

```
layout (std430, binding=2) buffer particles
{
    particle ps[];
};
layout (std430, binding=3) buffer spheres
{
    sphere ss[];
};
```

The part I am unclear on is the `binding=X`.  My setup code has the following:

```
        GLuint block_index =
            glGetProgramResourceIndex(
                compute_shader->getProgramId(),
                GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK,
                "particles");
        GLuint ssbo_binding_point_index = 2;
        GL_CALL(glShaderStorageBlockBinding,
            compute_shader->getProgramId(),
            block_index,
            ssbo_binding_point_index);
```

(Note, `GL_CALL` just forwards the call and checks for errors afterwards.)

Finally, I before each invocation of the compute shader I have:

```
GL_CALL(glBindBufferBase, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, particles->bufferId());
GL_CALL(glUseProgram, compute_shader->getProgramId());
```

This works, but it seems overly complicated.  *Is there a simpler way?*  Why can't I just query the set the buffer base like any other uniform?

Thanks!

Comment: The tutorial you linked to already told you what my answer did: "Actually this last step is not required: the binding point can be hard coded directly in the GLSL shader in the buffer layout:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `layout(binding = #)`, you're *already setting* the block binding index for the SSBO. You don't need to set it again from code; not unless you're *changing* the index to a new one. And you're using the same index here.

So just bind the buffer and move forward.

Comment: So wait, is anything above unnecessary? Or by "move forward" are you saying "live with it"? (which is fine too)

Comment: @Tim: What part of "you don't need to set it again from code" did you not understand?